# C++ Segmentation fault -- Self-balancing Tree insertion

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, avl-tree

I'm trying to solve a self-balancing tree problem on Hackerrank (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/self-balancing-tree/problem) and I keep getting a Segmentation fault in the last 3 test cases. I saw that this same problem had been posted before and tried to apply the same approach (check for nullptr) to my case, but no success so far. The following code is written in C++ and I would appreciate a lot if you guys could help me out. Thanks!

```
/* Node is defined as :
typedef struct node
{
    int val;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
    int ht;
} node; */

node * newNode(int val)
{
    node * newNode = new node;
    
    newNode->val = val;
    newNode->left = nullptr;
    newNode->right = nullptr;
    newNode->ht = 0;
    
    return newNode;
}

int getHeight(node* root)
{
    if(root == nullptr) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return root->ht;
    }
}

node* rightRotate(node* root)
{
    node* temp = root->left;
    root->left = temp->right;
    temp->right = root;

    root->ht = 1 + max(getHeight(root->left), getHeight(root->right));
    temp->ht = 1 + max(getHeight(temp->left), getHeight(temp->right));

    return temp;
}

node* leftRotate(node* root)
{
    node* temp = root->right;
    root->right = temp->left;
    temp->left = root;

    root->ht = 1 + max(getHeight(root->left), getHeight(root->right));
    temp->ht = 1 + max(getHeight(temp->left), getHeight(temp->right));

    return temp;
}

node * insert(node * root,int val)
{
    if(root == nullptr) {
        root = newNode(val); 
        return root;
    }
    if(val > root->val) {
        root->right = insert(root->right, val);
    }
    else if(val < root->val) {
        root->left = insert(root->left, val);
    }
    else{ return 0; }
    
    root->ht = 1 + max(getHeight(root->left),getHeight(root->right));
  
    int balance = getHeight(root->left) - getHeight(root->right);
    
    if(root->left != nullptr && balance > 1) {//Left subtree disbalanced
        if(val < root->left->val) { 
            //Left-Left case: perform a right rotation on the disb. node
            return rightRotate(root);
        }
        else {
            //Left-Right case: perfom a left rotation on the disb. node left subtree
            //and a right rotation on the disb. node
            root->left = leftRotate(root->left);
            return rightRotate(root);

        }
    }
    if(root->right != nullptr && balance < -1) {//Right subtree disbalanced
        if(val > root->right->val) { 
            //Right-Right case: perform a left rotation on the disb. node
            return leftRotate(root);
        }
        else {
            //Right-Left case: perfom a right rotation on the disb. node right subtree
            //and a left rotation on the disb. node
            root->right = rightRotate(root->left);
            return leftRotate(root);
        }
    }
    return root;
}
```

Edit:

For debugging purposes I've used an online gdb and added to the code above the following traversal method and main function:

```
void inOrder(node* root) {
    if(root == NULL) {
        return;
    } else {
        inOrder(root->left);
        cout << root->val << " ";
        inOrder(root->right);
    }
}

int main()
{
    node* root=NULL;

    root=insert(root,2);
    root=insert(root,4);
    root=insert(root,3);
    
    inOrder(root);
    return 0;
}
```

After trying to insert the values 2, 4 and 3, in this order, we would have a disbalanced tree since the right subtree would have a height of 1 while the left subtree would have a height of -1 (leaf node is nullptr) and the balance factor would be less than -1. Further analysis shows that we have a RIGHT-LEFT case since the node causing the disbalance is the left child of the right child of the disbalanced node (root 2). We would then have to perform a right rotation on the disbalanced node right child followed by a left rotation on the disbalanced node itself, and the tree should end up looking like the following:

```
   3
  / \
 2   4
```

Comment: What's the expected behavior when inserting a value that is already in the tree?

Comment: Hi @1201ProgramAlarm , thanks for replying, to answer your comment, it cannot have repeated values.

Comment: I think the reason they are asking is because if you try to insert a duplicate value, your program is going to destroy part of the tree and also leak memory.  Now, that may not be the whole reason your program is breaking, but it's also not a desirable behavior.  In other words, they are directly trying to draw your attention to an issue.  They didn't ask just because they're curious.

Comment: Hi @paddy, thanks for your explanation and reply, I think I missed the point. I removed the `else{ return 0; }` that could cause the issue you mentioned, it didn't solve the segmentation fault, but I'm glad you pointed that out, I completely missed that.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including inputs and expected outputs. Have you tried using a debugger to see where it is crashing?

Comment: Hello @AlanBirtles, my bad, I should have done that from the start, thanks for mentioning, I've added the minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who tried helping me out on this one, it turns out there is no limit to how dumb I can be. I believe I've figured out what I had done wrong.
The problem in this question lies on the section that checks if the right subtree is disbalanced and, if so, performs the necessary rotations. On the code piece below, it should be

```
root->right = rightRotate(root->right);
```

instead of

```
root->right = rightRotate(root->left);
```